# Is Redis LPOP / RPOP operation atomic?

Tags: redis

I am trying to build FIFO queue in Redis, but I am just worried about concurrency. What if 2 clients try to do RPOP operation simultaneously?

If RPOP/LPOP is not atomic then how can I achieve atomicity using MULTI/EXEC ?

Answer (score 14):

> Is Redis LPOP / RPOP operation atomic?

Yes, both `LPOP` and `RPOP` are atomic.

> What if 2 clients try to do RPOP operation simultaneously?

If the size of the `LIST` is equal to or greater than `2`, both clients get a different item. If the `LIST` has only one item, only one client gets the item, and the other client gets null reply. If the `LIST` is empty, both clients get null reply.

**Another Solution**

You can also use `BLPOP` or `BRPOP` to implement the `FIFO`. These two commands are also atomic and will block for empty `LIST`. See the doc for details.